# Codeigniter google maps how to get panorama ID

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps

I am using this library 
https://github.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library
in street view it works fine but i want to get image in view and it show different location

```
<img alt="21st Avenue Bicycles" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=205x150&amp&location=45.383637,-122.580853&heading=235;sensor=false&amp;key=AIzaSyBKEQ_OCmyImvabDEFHfo0gT8-EmxXIcOY">
```

it my code 
i have search and found that i need to pass panorama id instead of location. But i don't know how to get it any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you with google maps how to get panorama ID.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview